# What is the use of observable function in Dart?

Tags: dart, observable

I understand that an `@observable` variables or properties will be able to get in sync with the HTML counterpart when the value of either one changes.

What I don't get is the purpose/significance of `@observable` **function** in general and in [adlibitum](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/blob/master/web/target07/adlibitum/web/adlibitum.dart#L13) [example](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/templates/):

```dart
@observable bool show() {
  if (sillyword != '' && adjective != '' &&
      animal    != '' && bodypart  != '' &&
      verb      != '' && adverb    != '') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and its HTML counterpart:

```dart
<template instantiate="if show()">
  <p>Dear Ms. {{sillyword}},</p>

  <p>Little {{adjective}} Billy missed school
  because he was sick with wild-{{animal}} flu.
  His {{bodypart}} swelled up and fell off.
  He can no longer {{verb}}.</p>

  <p>Most {{adverb}} yours, Billy's mother</p>
</template>
```

And in what kind of situation `@observable` function ***is*** useful?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the `@observable` before the `show()` function determines whether the `<template>` gets activated or not. If `show()` starts to return `true`, maybe because `sillyword`, `adjective`, etc. all became non-empty strings, the `<template>` would get activated.

That's the general principle, anyway,

But, in this specific example, all the strings used within are also marked `@observable`:

```dart
@observable String sillyword='';
@observable String adjective='';
@observable String animal='';
@observable String bodypart='';
@observable String verb='';
@observable String adverb='';
```

This makes the `@observable` declaration right before `show()` unnecessary. If you remove that particular `@observable`, the code still works.

Comment: I have tested `@observable` on a method without having `@observable` fields and it does not react to changes in the return value.

Comment: That is correct, @PixelElephant. If the fields are observable, the method need not be observable, but if the fields are not observable, but the method is observable, the dynamic binding does not happen.

Comment: So then it seems that there is no point to marking a method observable?

Comment: That is correct. In this example, the @observable before `show()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @PixelElephant if the function is observable and the fields are not observable, the fields need to be updated via on-change event. Though I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Yes, it just seems confusing to ever use the annotation on a method. On a field it means something, so if I saw it on a method I would assume the same thing, but really it does nothing.

Comment: I still don't understand in what kind of situation `@observable` function *is* useful.